# jquery spellchecker on several inputs

Tags: jquery, spell-checking

I'm using https://github.com/badsyntax/jquery-spellchecker on a form, and I want to apply it to several text inputs rather than one textarea.

The general idea is this:

```
var spellchecker = new $.SpellChecker('.my-class', {
    lang: 'en',
    parser: 'text',
    engine: {
      path: '/path/to/engines/php/spellchecker.php',
      driver: 'google'
    }
  });
```

How can I target each input individually without spellchecker assigning the chosen suggestion to all inputs?

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the plugin, and have added support for multiple fields.

Here is how you can do it:

```js
(function() {

  var fields = $('input:text,textarea');

  // Init the text spellchecker
  var spellchecker = new $.SpellChecker(fields, {
    lang: 'en',
    parser: 'text',
    webservice: {
      path: '../php/spellchecker.php',
      driver: 'pspell'
    },
    suggestBox: {
      position: 'above'
    },
    incorrectWords: {
      position: function(container) {
        this.after(container);
      }
    }
  });

  // Bind spellchecker handler functions
  spellchecker.on('check.success', function() {
    alert('There are no incorrectly spelt words.');
  });

  // Check the spelling
  $("#check-textarea").click(function(e){
    spellchecker.check();
  });
})();
```

- [Fancy demo](http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/multiple-fields.html)
- [Basic demo](http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/basic/multiple-fields.html)

[Download](https://github.com/badsyntax/jquery-spellchecker/downloads) the latest version of the plugin (currently 0.2.1) to get this new feature.

Comment: Thanks!  I saw that you updated it just as I was about to look for another solution.  Very useful plugin.  Thank you!